# SVN Ignore PowerPoint file changes

Tags: svn, powerpoint

I must be missing something. I use SVN on PowerPoint file.

[Editing the following to better describe the steps]

**Step 1:** Create a new repository.

**Step 2:** Use PowerPoint to create a ppt (call it signal.ppt).

**Step 3:** Add signal.ppt into svn.

**Step 4:** Commit signal.ppt into svn.

**Step 5:** Make a copy of signal.ppt and name it good.ppt.

**Step 6:** Open signal.ppt in PowerPoint and close it right away. I do not make any change and I do not do File --> Save.

**Step 7:** I do 'svn status signal.ppt' and svn will say that there is no change.

**Step 8:** I compare every byte between signal.ppt and good.ppt and 1051 bytes (out of 6,561,792 bytes) are different.

So the question is: how can 'svn status' miss the change?

Also note that I have tried to remove some of the slides in test.ppt. Once I do that, the problem goes away (i.e. 'svn status' correctly reports the change).

I am really lost on what is going on here.

I guess maybe I am the only one having this problem.

Comment: Please, give more details about your case. You could use the svn copy command to copy files within your working copy or a repository.

Comment: But my question is not about "svn copy" or making copy of files. 

Basically the file is modified by PowerPoint (some of the bytes are changed) but somehow svn says that there is no change in the file.

Comment: You need to show an actual example. Now it’s unclear what happens.

Comment: Possibly SVN is acting intelligently and ignoring the couple of bytes that PPT changes when you open a file and close it w/o making any changes, e.g. the Last Accessed time/date that it stores when you do that.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am hoping SVN does not do that. 

Also to rule out this possibility, once I open-and-close the ppt file (let call this file "test.ppt"). I save a copy of this ppt file to another filename (bad.ppt). Now svn will say that there is no change in test.ppt.

Then I delete test.ppt and rename bad.ppt to test.ppt. Now svn says that test.ppt is changed.

I know that this is very strange. I just cannot explain what I am seeing.

Comment: @Kevin if you save `test.ppt` as `bad.ppt` the `test.ppt` doesn't change (IMHO). If you've a ppt 1) add it to svn. After 2) open and close it in PowerPoint. 3) See `svn status`. What happened?

Comment: Hi uzsolt, the answer to your question is: svn will report no modification. But if you compare every single byte between test.ppt and bad.ppt, then there are differences.

Answer (score 0):

I just talked to my co-worker about this and he came up with a theory. I think he is correct (but there is no way for me to 100% confirm that).

His theory is that svn relies on Windows notification. I believe windows has a mechanism to keep track of what files are being modified. In this case, since microsoft owns both windows and powerpoint, in theory windows can report signal.ppt is not changed (since I just open-and-close it, so I did not make any change) and it seems to us that 'svn st' uses this mechanism.

We also try this using git and 'git status' does not have this same problem as 'svn status'.

In short, after all, one can argue that this is not a real problem. Even though signal.ppt file content is modified, there is no real change and so I don't need to commit the changes into svn.

One way to force a change is to use "touch":

> >> copy /b signal.ppt +,, signal.ppt

Another potential solution is to use pptx file (instead of ppt file). I try this on signal.ppt (use save-as to signal.pptx in powerpoint) and it seems to work (in this case, open-and-close a pptx file does not change file content (not even one byte)).